# Generate generate OAuth2 access token with additional claims to JUnit test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-test

I have spring boot REST API secured using OAuth2. My authentication server and resource server are two applications. All the REST API security properly working with REST client.
Then I need to write security test cases. I generate access token using following code. Some end points need manually added claims inside REST method. 
Program given valid access token, but claims not include in this token.

```
private String generateToken(String... authorities) {

    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey("123");

    tokenService = new DefaultTokenServices();

    JwtTokenStore jwtTokenStore = new JwtTokenStore(converter);
    tokenService.setTokenStore(jwtTokenStore);

    tokenService.setTokenEnhancer(converter);

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();

    if (authorities != null) {
        for (String authority: authorities) {
            grantAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority));
        }
    }

    Set<String> resourceIds = Collections.emptySet();
    Set<String> scopes = Collections.emptySet();

    Map<String, String> requestParameters = Collections.emptyMap();
    boolean approved = true;
    String redirectUrl = null;
    Set<String> responseTypes = Collections.emptySet();
    Map<String, Serializable> extensionProperties = Collections.emptyMap();

    OAuth2Request oAuth2Request = new OAuth2Request(requestParameters, "web-client", grantAuthorities,
            approved, scopes, resourceIds, redirectUrl, responseTypes, extensionProperties);

    User userPrincipal = new User("user", "", true, true,
            true, true, grantAuthorities);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userPrincipal, null, grantAuthorities);

    OAuth2Authentication auth = new OAuth2Authentication(oAuth2Request, authenticationToken);

    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenService.createAccessToken(auth);

    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();

    List<Long> tenantIds = new ArrayList<>();
    tenantIds.add(1L);

    claims.put("role", 1L);
    claims.put("tenants", tenantIds);

    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(claims);

    return accessToken.getValue();

}
```

How I add claims to this token.

Comment: what do you mean by "claims"? is it grand authorities?

Comment: Not grant authorities. They are OK. But other parameters like "role", "tenants" etc..

Comment: if you get some token, like `aaaa1`, and you want to add here some `role` like `admin`, new token with new claim will not be `aaaa1`. so, you need to generate token once, with all information inside, tokens live without modification. look at JWT, where you can store `payload` data about user

Comment: Is there any way to generate token with claims one time.

Comment: look at your `OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenService.createAccessToken(auth); ` code line. inspect `createAccessToken` method, and make modification, to add claims in your token

Comment: Do you have any example code??

Comment: it expects from you, you should show us, what have you done, where you stack, and what is your problem.

Comment: @BSeitkazin I found the solution and posted it in answer. Thank you for your commitment

Answer (score -1):

Finally found the solution. Add **TokenEnhancerChain** to code

Following is the final code

```
private String generateToken(String... authorities) {

    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey("123");

    tokenService = new DefaultTokenServices();

    JwtTokenStore jwtTokenStore = new JwtTokenStore(converter);
    tokenService.setTokenStore(jwtTokenStore);

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();

    if (authorities != null) {
        for (String authority: authorities) {
            grantAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority));
        }
    }

    Set<String> resourceIds = Collections.emptySet();
    Set<String> scopes = Collections.emptySet();

    Map<String, String> requestParameters = Collections.emptyMap();
    boolean approved = true;
    String redirectUrl = null;
    Set<String> responseTypes = Collections.emptySet();
    Map<String, Serializable> extensionProperties = Collections.emptyMap();

    OAuth2Request oAuth2Request = new OAuth2Request(requestParameters, "web-client", grantAuthorities,
            approved, scopes, resourceIds, redirectUrl, responseTypes, extensionProperties);

    User userPrincipal = new User("user", "", true, true,
            true, true, grantAuthorities);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userPrincipal, null, grantAuthorities);

    OAuth2Authentication auth = new OAuth2Authentication(oAuth2Request, authenticationToken);

    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();

    List<Long> tenantIds = new ArrayList<>();
    tenantIds.add(1L);

    claims.put("role", 1L);
    claims.put("tenants", tenantIds);

    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenService.createAccessToken(auth);

    TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
            Arrays.asList(new CustomTokenEnhancer(), converter));

    accessToken = tokenEnhancerChain.enhance(accessToken, auth);

    return accessToken.getValue();

}
```

IMPORTANT : Add JwtAccessTokenConverter as final element of token enhancer list

Following is the CustomTokenEnhancer class.

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();

        List<Long> tenantIds = new ArrayList<>();
        tenantIds.add(1L);

        claims.put("role", 1L);
        claims.put("tenants", tenantIds);
        claims.put("userId", "admin@abc.com");

        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(claims);

        return accessToken;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is `DefaultTokenServices`? How `OAuth2Request ` behaviour?  How `OAuth2Authentication ` works and where it authenticate? In suggested answer, you say, just add `tokenEnhancerChain`, but inside you use `CustomTokenEnhancer` class, how it works? It looks like, you just posted question, to answer on it by yourself.

Comment: Sorry. I edit answer with CutomTokenEnhancer code. This is only for the testing. Create JWT token with claims for the testing.